# discord.js mention command not picking up users but picks up itself

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I've started my bot after a while and for some reason the mention command is not working. Code and response to the command is below:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('L!bite')) {
        let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (!targetMember) return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to bite them!!');
        // message goes below!
        message.channel.send(`${targetMember.user}, You just got a bitten!`);
        message.channel.send({files:["./nom/"]})
        //let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        //embed.setImage(`https://media1.tenor.com/images/4f5666861516073c1c8015b2af7e2d15/tenor.gif?itemid=14720869`)
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

Response on Discord: (it does picks itself up as a user but not anyone else)

```
·._.•    •._.·Today at 1:18 PM
L!bite @·._.•    •._.·

._.·♡·._.BOT Today at 1:18 PM
@·._.•    •._.·, you need to tag a user in order to bite them!!
```

I'm just confused on why it's saying that I'm or other people are not users, but it picks up itself? E.g.:

```
·._.•    •._.·Today at 1:18 PM
L!bite @._.·♡·._.

._.·♡·._.BOT Today at 1:18 PM
@._.·♡·._., You just got a bitten!
GIF HERE
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine for me, even with those ribbons and hearts in the username: https://imgur.com/a/i4f06TH (I only changed `RichEmbed` to `MessageEmbed` as I'm using discord.js v12).

Comment: That’s the weirdest Part my node cmd prompt it maybe if I cut and copy to a new coding page? Idk I’m completely confused

Comment: Are you using discord.js v11?

Comment: ` "author": "FBILOLIGIRL",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },`
this what i got

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the `message.mentions.members` to array and then filter your bot! -

```js
const mentions = message.mentions.members.array() // will return members array of GuildMember class

const firstMention = mentions.filter(mention=> !mention.user.id === "BOT_ID")[0]
```

Comment: could i have an example of what you mean?
in terms of the array?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
converting discord.js collection into array - https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=array

Comment: hymmm ima sound dumb af rn but its very confusing

Comment: unfortunately idk anything about arrays so I'm going to see other answers unless you can explain it better because atm it's confusing

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, there's already a parameter you can implement in your code where it can automatically check if the message came from a bot. Although, this process may not work if you want to have other bots automatically tag it, but I think that's unlikely.
`if (message.author.bot) return;` FYI, not sure of which version of discord.js you're using, but the embed naming convention has changed. Instead of `RichEmbed()`, you should use `MessageEmbed()`.
So the place you would implement this is right after your first `if` conditional block, like this:

```
if (message.content.startsWith('L!bite')) {
    //the thing that checks if the user who posted was the bot
    if (message.author.bot) return;
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: `                message.channel.send(`${targetMember.user}, ouch you just got slapped that would of hurt!`);
                                                           ^
thats the error that i get with it T^T
as for the message emblem i don't use that anymore thats there as a old code thats the reason it has //
thank you for trying!!!

Comment: I don't see the code ```message.channel.send${targetMember.user}, ouch you just got slapped that would of hurt!``` block in your code here.

Comment: so the `($ {targetmember.user} is the problem it's for some reason stopping the messsage from going through
its a different cmd with the same basics

Comment: So does that mean the bot doesn't register anything except for itself? Then I would recommend adding `if (message.author.bot) return;` before the `if` conditional of that command as well.

Comment: See this command I had didn’t have a problem before and other users have used my code with out a problem

Comment: Yeah, but I'm confused as to why this command would affect the other separate command. What do you input in the other command that causes it to give you an error?

Comment: The error goes for too long it’s the arrow up ward to the target member.user part that it doesn’t like

Comment: Maybe try changing it from `targetMember.user` to `targetMember.username` or just delete the `user` part altogether.

Comment: I’ll give it a try

Comment: Could you maybe edit your post to include your other command as well so I can check for differences?